# Error-free download of reactive objects in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Shiny experts!

In our application we have download button for plot downloading. The button is working only when some data are loaded and processed. When you push the button before, there is an error message from plotting function, because it has no data.

```
content = function(file) {
            r <- rChart_line_plot(follow_view_func(),log_scale = input$checkbox_log_scale_plot,isRel = input$checkboxRelativeTab2)
            r$save(file, standalone = TRUE)
        }
```

We want to make our app foolproof and error-free. Is there any possible way to send to downloadHandler's content "NULL"? This don't work.

```
content = function(file) {
          if ( "our data are ready for printing" ) {
            r <- rChart_line_plot(follow_view_func(),log_scale = input$checkbox_log_scale_plot,isRel = input$checkboxRelativeTab2)
            r$save(file, standalone = TRUE)
          } else {
            NULL
          }
        }
```

And we're getting:

```
Error opening file: 2
Error reading: 9
```

Is there something like validate() function with even information for user "Please load file first"

Thank You a lot.

Comment: Would it possible to post the rest of your application code - i.e. the complete `ui.R` and `server.R` files?

Comment: Each of them have more than 1000 lines.. I'm probably asking for help especially with downloadHandler() function - if there any way to silence its errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that you want a `validate` statement.  Here is a [link](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/validation.html) with descriptions from the RStudio team.  This will allow you to have a more informative error message.  Your complete `downloadHandler` function would look something like the following.  Note that this assumes your dataset could be null.

```
output$Download <- downloadHandler(
                filename = function() {
                    paste("test.png",sep="")
                },
                content = function(file) {
                    myData <- follow_view_func()
                    validate(
                        need(!is.null(myData), "Please select valid dataset")
                    )
                    r <- rChart_line_plot(myData,log_scale = input$checkbox_log_scale_plot,isRel = input$checkboxRelativeTab2)
                    r$save(file, standalone = TRUE)
                }
            )
```

Here is a complete reproducible example with the `iris` dataset.

```
library(shiny)
library(rCharts)
runApp(
    list(
        ui = pageWithSidebar(
            headerPanel("Using 'validate' for useful error messages"),

            sidebarPanel(
                selectInput("dataset", "Choose a dataset:", 
                            choices = c("null", "iris")),
                selectInput(inputId = "x",
                            label = "Choose X",
                            choices = c('SepalLength', 'SepalWidth', 'PetalLength', 'PetalWidth'),
                            selected = "SepalLength"),
                selectInput(inputId = "y",
                            label = "Choose Y",
                            choices = c('SepalLength', 'SepalWidth', 'PetalLength', 'PetalWidth'),
                            selected = "SepalWidth"),
                downloadButton("Download")
            ),
            mainPanel(
                showOutput("myChart", "polycharts")
            )
        ),

        server = function(input, output) { 

            datasetInput <- reactive({
                switch(input$dataset,
                       "iris" = iris,
                       "null" = NULL)
            })

            myChart <- reactive({
                myData <- datasetInput()
                validate(
                    need(!is.null(myData), "Please select valid dataset")
                )
                names(myData) = gsub("\\.", "", names(myData))
                p1 <- rPlot(input$x, input$y, data = myData, color = "Species", 
                            facet = "Species", type = 'point')
                p1$addParams(dom = 'myChart')
                return(p1)
            })

            output$myChart <- renderChart({myChart()})

            output$Download <- downloadHandler(
                filename = function() {
                    paste("test.png",sep="")
                },
                content = function(file) {
                    p1 <- myChart()
                    p1$save(file, standalone = TRUE)
                }
            )
        }
        )
    )
```

**UPDATE**

As per the OP request, it may be ideal to have no error whatsoever with the download button.  The only solution I could come up with is to make the button a `conditionalPanel`.  This intuitively makes sense to me because why would you download if there is nothing on the screen?  The only change in the code above needed for this is to change:

```
downloadButton("Download")
```

to

```
conditionalPanel("output.myChart", downloadButton("Download"))
```

Now the download button will only be present when a valid chart is created.

Comment: Thank you, this is it! But there is still error output in Console:Error : 'Please select valid dataset'. Can I get rid of it somehow? Like redirect output somewhere else? Because validate() in other parts of the code only displays message in UI.

Comment: Well usually I imagine the user would want to know the error immediately but if you want it redirected I'm sure you could set some sort of log file and save to that for someone to inspect after the fact.  Is that something that would work for you?

Comment: That's not exactly what I meant. I would like to keep Console nice and clean without errors. So I want to show error/validate messages only in UI. With redirection I meant something like '2>/dev/null' for error showing in Console.

Comment: Correct me if I am mistaken now, you want the error message in the UI but not in the pop-up when you try and download in which you would prefer just a blank pop-up?

Comment: No, I'm talking about error message in Console/Terminal where the R is running. The best would be no window popping-up and the only error message should display in UI, but it would be more than I expected. :)

Comment: See my edit above, a `conditionalPanel` is the only solution I could think of , otherwise I think you are stuck with a simple error message.